# SSH using NetBeans to Ubuntu

Tags: php, netbeans, ssh

I want to edit a website hosted on `Ubuntu 12.04 Server` from `Windows 8.1` through `NetBeans 7.3.1` using `SSH`

I tried this but getting this error.

[image]

I can successfully `SSH` to that Ubuntu machine through other PCs.

Comment: is ubuntu a defined hostname on your machine? You should enter the real hostname or ip address in Host Name field. The hostname you entered is not valid

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not related to NetBeans. Host Name `ubuntu` provided is not a valid hostname.

Try running this command on Command Prompt (`cmd`):

```
ping ubuntu
```

It will most likely return with this error message:

`Ping request could not find host ubuntu. Please check the name and try again.`

It works on other PCs you mentioned in the question because:

1. They have the host in their hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts). E.g:

   ```
   192.168.0.16 ubuntu
   ```
2. They are using different DNS servers

You can get the IP address of the Ubuntu machine by logging into it and getting the IP address from the response of the following command:

```
ifconfig
```

You can update your hosts file using the IP.